# Show transformation on function is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For transformation $P:X\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is the space of continuous functions $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$Pf(x) = \frac{1}{2}*(f(x)+f(-x))$$

How do I show that $P$ is linear and that $P*P=P$? It seems to me that $P$ is only linear if $f$ is linear, but how would I know that? Are all continuous functions on $[1,-1]$ linear? Why?

Comment: Keep in mind that for linearity we think of $P$ as acting on $f$, not on $x$.  Start by writing down $P(f+g)(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(P*P)f=\frac{1}{2}([\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(-x)]+[\frac{1}{2}f(-x)+\frac{1}{2}f(x)])=[\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(-x)]=Pf$
2. $P$ is linear as an operator, $P(af+bg)=aP(f)+bP(g)$. That doesn't mean that $Pf$ is always linear function.
3. No. $sin(x)$ is nonlinear, for example. But continuous. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose that $f,g\in X$. You need to show that $P(f+g) = Pf + Pg$ and $P(\alpha f) = \alpha Pf$, for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.  Recall that $f+g$ is defined by $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$, for $x\in [-1,1]$. Similarly $\alpha f$ is defined by $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)$, for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that linearity of an operator is defined by
$$P(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda P(f)(x),\ P(f+g)(x) = P(f)(x) + P(g)(x)$$
Where addition and scaling of functions is defined pointwise. Thus
$$P(\lambda f)(x) = \frac12 ((\lambda f)(x) + (\lambda f)(-x)) = \frac12 (\lambda f(x) + \lambda f(-x)) = \lambda \frac12 (f(x) +f(-x)) = \lambda P(f)(x) \\
P(f+g)(x) = \frac12 ((f+g)(x) + (f+g)(-x)) = \ldots$$
can you do the rest yourself?